# Android - Canvas - load image from file, modify it and save the complete result to a file

Tags: android, android-canvas

Upon entry of the canvas, I would like to load an image from a file. 
Then I would like to modify it and finally store it to the same file.

Via a button the image is loaded (or updated) into the myBitMap.

Method 1: does not work.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if( myBitMap != null) { 
        // I added an image to it via a button
        canvas = new Canvas( myBitMap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true));
        myBitMap = null; 
    }
    // rest of the drawing code
```

Method 2: does work ... but needs both redrawing of my loaded image and the newly changed stuff. So, at each change (onTouch...) I need to redraw BOTH images.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if( myBitMap != null) canvas.drawBitmap( myBitMap, 0, 0, null); 
    // rest of the drawing code
```

Why is this?

Is there a way to put the loaded image into the bitmap the canvas is using? Then there is 1 complete bitmap that is changed with onTouchEvents.

Comment: draw on the Bitmap's Canvas and then draw the Bitmap itself on the View's Canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: draw on the loaded bitmap and draw the whole to the View's canvas.

- Load from the file the bitmap.
- Draw that bitmap on the canvas of the View, e.g. canvas.DrawBitmap( bitmap, 0, 0, null);
- The new (interactive) drawing could also be done directly on the canvas.
- Save the whole by reading from the DrawingCache.

The disadvantage is that if you use scrolling, anything outside the viewport is clipped. The standard drawingcache has a limited size.

Option 2: draw on a bitmap and finally draw that on the View's canvas.

- Load from the file the bitmap, e.g. loadedBitmap.
- Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas( loadedBitmap);
- myCanvas.drawRect( .... );
- More drawing actions and finally ...
- canvas.drawBitmap( loadedBitmap);
- This loadedBitmap can of course be easily written to a file (e.g. a PNG).

The bitmap should be mutable (imMutable = true).

Option 3: create your own cachedBitmap with your own size

This is similar to option 2, but you can then define a bitmap with your specific size. You could start by copying the loadedBitmap into your new bitmap, etc.